# Cloud config starts throwing errors about missing repository

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-client

### Intro

We have a cloud config service based on spring cloud-cloud-config that connects to a bitbucket repository.

For the most part, things are working fine.
However, once in a while we get an error suddenly and it mentions a repository in the temporary folder that I am not aware of.

### Important Log Message

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found: 
C:\Windows\Temp\config-repo-5198690406799233048
```

### Full Log

```
`2023-02-16 14:54:07.370 DEBUG 11516 --- [io-8888-exec-10] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 0000
2023-02-16 14:54:07.370 DEBUG 11516 --- [io-8888-exec-10] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 93c4f6563b430301e4a4c8e275d5b5e64b5a321a HEAD multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed allow-tip-sha1-in-want allow-reachable-sha1-in-want no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master filter object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.35.3
2023-02-16 14:54:07.370 DEBUG 11516 --- [io-8888-exec-10] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 93c4f6563b430301e4a4c8e275d5b5e64b5a321a refs/heads/master
2023-02-16 14:54:07.370 DEBUG 11516 --- [io-8888-exec-10] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 4780d270f79633ab8a609ff7b8390423376ec5e6 refs/tags/April7_2020
2023-02-16 14:54:07.370 DEBUG 11516 --- [io-8888-exec-10] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 0000
2023-02-16 15:04:11.345 DEBUG 11516 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< # service=git-upload-pack
2023-02-16 15:04:11.345 DEBUG 11516 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 0000
2023-02-16 15:04:11.345 DEBUG 11516 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 93c4f6563b430301e4a4c8e275d5b5e64b5a321a HEAD multi_ack thin-pack side-band side-band-64k ofs-delta shallow deepen-since deepen-not deepen-relative no-progress include-tag multi_ack_detailed allow-tip-sha1-in-want allow-reachable-sha1-in-want no-done symref=HEAD:refs/heads/master filter object-format=sha1 agent=git/2.35.3
2023-02-16 15:04:11.345 DEBUG 11516 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 93c4f6563b430301e4a4c8e275d5b5e64b5a321a refs/heads/master
2023-02-16 15:04:11.345 DEBUG 11516 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 4780d270f79633ab8a609ff7b8390423376ec5e6 refs/tags/April7_2020
2023-02-16 15:04:11.345 DEBUG 11516 --- [nio-8888-exec-2] org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn  : git< 0000
2023-02-16 15:11:50.743 ERROR 11516 --- [io-8888-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load environment] with root cause

org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found: C:\Windows\Temp\config-repo-5198690406799233048
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:614) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar!/:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git.open(Git.java:122) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar!/:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git.open(Git.java:102) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-4.11.0.201803080745-r.jar!/:4.11.0.201803080745-r]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository$JGitFactory.getGitByOpen(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:677) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.openGitRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:540) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:515) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:259) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:238) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:150) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:190) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:46) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:53) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.labelled(EnvironmentController.java:122) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]`
```

I have been debugging the issue and I restarted the server when it happened.
I am wondering though how to fix this so that it never happens - as it is disruptive and causes a 500 error.

### Update

We are starting to suspect that the issue is caused by the interference of an anti-virus. Investigating further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the antivirus installed on the server.
I added a rule to disable the antivirus and the errors stopped.